# Android screenshot and tutorial maker

Tags: android, image-editor, screenshot, annotation

Often I need to explain certain actions in an Android app.

What I usually do is take a bunch of screenshots. Then put those screenshots in a series like a step-by-step guide. Also annotate them, red-circle some parts, write "go here" etc.

I do all this in various photo editing softwares (MS Paint, Photoshop) depending on what's available and how much time I have.

I also have to first transfer the screenshots from my Android (where I took them) to my PC and then transfer the final output back to my phone in order to send forward them to whoever I need to send it to.

Is there an Android app that makes all this a bit easier? That does all the above (i.e. requirements):

- Takes screenshots

  - Optionally: Ability to crop (top and bottom bar, i.e. just screenshot the app)
  - Optionally: Blur/pixellate sensitive info
- Put those screenshots in a series to make a step-by-step guide
- Ability to annotate

OS: Android. License: Any

E.g.: [image]

Comment: Not entirely covering your needs: in the `tools/` directory of my Adebar you find a Bash script named [ssnap](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar/blob/master/tools/ssnap) (should also run in Cygwin). Via parameters you can a.o. specify which "time" it should set (it uses demo-mode for that, so time can e.g. reflect the app version number – and it "sanitizes" the notification bar). Then you walk your screens on your device, and hit "s" everytime you want to make a screenshot – "q" when done. You'd still need to do post-processing (blur etc) by other means.